# Remoting wirelessly into a wired raspberry pi

Tags: remote-desktop, wireless-router, raspberry-pi, remote-access, remote-connection

Not sure if this is the right forum for this question, I apologize if it isn't. I have plans to build a raspberry pi to do my downloading of large files. In the flat I live in, I want to keep my main computer in my room, but the router and connections are on the other side of the house, so a wired connection to my main isn't possible without ripping the walls up. I have my main using a wireless extender and averaging about 1MB/s for these downloads. Of course when I plug it in to the router, I'm pushing 3. I need to be able to remote into to the pi wirelessly, but also want it to use a wired connection for its downloads. Now for Remoting I would be connected wirelessly to the router (rather than the extender) that is also providing the Ethernet connection to the pi. Would this mean both computers would have the same IP, or are IP's assigned differently based on wired/wireless connections on the same router? Also supposing that the IP is the same, is what I'm thinking of possible to do? Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your Pi and your home PC will have the same external IP address, but different internal addresses. You should be able to remote in.